# How to check if Number is Even or Odd and Greater than 100?

Tags: actionscript-3, division, flash-cs6, modulus

Hey guys so I am wondering if this is possible. So in my game I have it set up to where if they make a point the score goes up by 5. I implemented a multiplier in the game so if they dont get hit and continue making points then the score could increase by 10,15, and 20 depending on if they get hit or not of course.

I have my Difficulty updater using a modulus to track every score interval of 100 then increase the difficulty. The **PROBLEM** I am having is if they have a multiplier at the time and instead of getting 100 they get 105 the modulus doesnt take that into consideration and the function is never called.

Here is how I have it set up:

```
private function udpateDifficutlyModulus():void 
    {
        if (nScore % 100 == 0 && nScore > 0)
        {

            seagullNumber -= 0.5
            eelNumber -= 0.5
            trace("Update Modulus difficulty");
            addBombs();
        }
    }
```

Now this works fine if they score is divisible by 100 but like I stated before sometimes its 105 or 115 etc...

I think I have to check somehow if the score is odd or even and greater than 100? I just don't know how I would go about doing that? \

Any help of course will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: do you know that if a number X is even it can be divided by 2, and therefore (X % 2) == 0 . I let you guess the similar test for odd numbers..

Comment: You seem to know how to verify if nScore is greater than 0. The check for nScore being greater than 100 is similar.

Comment: I understand but i was wanting to check if the nScore is greater by 100, 200, 300 etc... Trying to see if there was an easier method rather than multiple if statements

Comment: It is hard to answer to questions that are not asked. Are you asking how to write               if (nScore > 100 && nScore % 2 == 0)                with a single if statement ?

Comment: Yeah, why not:  iNextLevelUp = 100;  if(iScore >= iNextLevelUp){...}  Then calculate the iNextLevelUp when it's reached?

Comment: I don't know if I understood your question, but are you trying to update your game difficulty level every 100 point : `0 -> 99 : level 1, 100 -> 199 : level 2, 200 -> 299 : level 3, etc  ` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way you've framed the question may not actually fit well with your problem. If you want to know each time your score passes a 100 increment, you could simply do this:

```
// represents current hundreds (1=100, 2=200, etc)
private var currentLevel:int = 0;

// each time score changes
private function checkCurrentLevel():void {
    var newLevel:int = score / 100;
    if(newLevel > currentLevel){
        // do difficulty increment
        currentLevel = newLevel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this looks perfect so simple.  But for some reason it's not working correctly. When I reach 100 the difficulty increases but whenever I score another point it keeps increasing the difficulty so on and so on. After it reaches 100 I trace the if statement and its being called every time I score any points after that. What could be causing this?

Comment: Make sure you update `currentLevel` within your update function.

Comment: Also `currentLevel` is supposed to be a game state variable on some class, not local to your update function. I've tweaked the example code to try to clarify this.

Comment: Of course it works perfect. Thanks so much. I had both variables as private and wasnt updating the newLevel inside the function.

Answer (score 2):

I am answering this a little quickly but is this the type of logic you are looking for?

```
if(nScore > 100) // score is greater than 100
{
   if(nScore % 2 == 0)
   {
      //even Nscore
   }
   else
   {
      //odd Nscore
   }
}
```

Comment: Pretty much this does trick to check if its even or odd. But I want to check this if statement every interval of 100. This does check for the first time the score is 100 but not if score is greater than 200 or 300 etc... Not sure how i would go about doing that? Maybe modulus in the first if statement?

Comment: You would need a range. Doing just >200 would also be hit by >100. So something like if((nScore % 100) <= 15) would do it on every interval with a padding of 15 since I'm guessing that you want the difficulty to go up once. Correct me if I'm misunderstanding.
Example: hits: 105, 215, 408, 600 non-hits: 298, 216, 320

Comment: The original question is "I have to check somehow if the score is odd or even and greater than 100? I just don't know how I would go about doing that?"

Comment: Yeah sorry I'm being confusing right now haha. I want the difficulty to go up every time the score reaches multiples of 100. so it will go up when the score is greater than or equal to 100, 200, 300, etc...

Comment: Sorry don't know how to change the question. But if you read the description you would understand that I meant. score is odd or even and by intervals of 100.

Comment: Intervals of 100 would be if(nScore %100 == 0). Sorry for confusion xD.

Comment: ok, you are asking for a logical expression to detect when the score, incremented by values of 5,10,15 cross a threshold that is a multiple of 100 ?  (oldScore > 0 && (oldScore % 100) > 50 && (newScore % 100) <= 50)  would help if the scores are never incremented by more than 50 at a time.

Comment: "odd and even" are understood that way . http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(mathematics) . Maybe you need to rephrase your question.